# What's the best pattern to synchronise a Room table with a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, synchronization, android-room

I have:

- a table for my entity, `obj`.
- a (model) class, `Obj`.
- a Room Entity, `ObjEntity`.
- a Room DAO, `ObjDao`.
- and finally a RecyclerView for my model, `Obj`.

---

Within my `Obj` class, I've added an insert method - `Obj#Post`, which handles storing this `Obj` to the app's database (handles converting to `ObjEntity`, foreign keys for child entities / lists, etc.)

The first thought is to requery the `obj` table for all `obj`s, before taking this `ObjEntity[]`, mapping it to a `Obj[]` before updating the (cached) in memory version of all `obj`s - and notifying the recycler view adapter of an update.

---

This obviously doesn't seem like the best approach, as it would only update on an insert, and not a delete etc. This also doesn't follow the pattern of separation of concerns.

---

What I ideally want is for the RecyclerView to dynamically query the database *itself*, and update accordingly. However, the implementation of the adapter works based off of an ordered list structure. Now, the `objs` won't always have nicely contiguous `id`s - so unless I did some funky hack to map from the value returned by `RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemCount` to each ID , this doesn't seem like it would work. Also, most importantly, there's no notifying of changes to the adapter with this solution. It'd just be querying whenever it usually does - I don't know the implementation, I'm guessing some form of polling, or user interaction trigger.

---

Does Room have some form of callback API, i.e. `ObjDao#onTableUpdated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is exactly designed in Android architecture component.

The `LiveData` notifies the view whenever there is a change in the Room Database.

The `ViewModel` handle the data operation independent to UI, that is complete CURD operation.

The `Repository` modules handle data operations. They provide a clean API so that the rest of the app can retrieve this data easily. They know where to get the data from and what API calls to make when data is updated. You can consider repositories to be mediators between different data sources, such as persistent models, web services, and caches.

[image: Android Architecture Component]

[App using these components](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#connect-viewmodel-repository)

If you want to use it for pagination purpose in the `recyclerview` use `PagedListAdapter` instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter`